# Why does misusing 1 instead of 1.0 from an int exceeding limits effect the value we get when we convert it to a double

Tags: java, integer, double

This is the code I will be using...

```
public class foo {
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int a = (int) Math.pow(2, 30);

        double d = (a + a - 1.0);
        double f = (a + a - 1);

        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(f);
    }


}
```

The outputs are -2.147483649E9 and 2.147483647E9.

I do not understand why these values are printed out. It is my understanding that a + a will exceed the limits of int and therefore will switch to being negative, however, f is positive. I would expect both to be negative but f would be fractional whilst d would be an double with a point 0 due to integer division.

Comment: [`a + a == Integer.MIN_VALUE` (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/tSHvbx).

Comment: "f would be fractional" why fractional? "due to integer division" which division?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case `a + a` overflows to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then you switch to a `double` context with `-1.0` which gives a negative number (`Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1`), since a `double` can hold a number smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

In the second example you stay in an `int` context, which means that `a + a` overflows to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then subtracting 1 from that underflows and takes you back to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking this apart step by step reveals the answer.

First, we observe that `a + a == Integer.MIN_VALUE` [<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tSHvbx).

Next, if the expression `a + a - 1.0` is evaluated, it is evaluated from left to right, i.e. it is equivalent to `(a + a) - 1.0`, which is equivalent to `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1.0`. Since the right hand side is a `double`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is converted to `double` as well, and the result is negative.

Finally, if the expression `a + a - 1` is evaluated, it is equivalent to `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1`. The whole operation is done in the `int`-space with ring arithmetic, and subracting `1` from the `MIN_VALUE` evaluates to the `MAX_VALUE`.